# Better practice alternative to large arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a way to store temporary data (it will be stored in a database through ajax after a few minutes of being in use). The method I've chosen is to create a huge array, with arrays inside and then use functions to isolate the required data.

Code available here: https://jsfiddle.net/44bjgykq/5/

```
var property_data = [[5,[[8,[1,3,3,7],[[4,2],[7,3],[1,4]]],[6,[5,5,5,5],[[2,3],[6,4],[3,2]]]]],[5,[[5,[1,1,1,1],[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]],[7,[1,1,1,1],[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]]]]];
```

I feel like this might not be the most efficient/best practice way to store data, but I might be wrong. What would be a better alternative if there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the absolute smallest footprint possibly then this is fine, albeit very hard to read and understand.

A more common approach would be to store it in a more friendly format, like a javascript object. For example:

```
var property = {
    propertyId: 5,
    rooms: [{
        roomId: 8
    },{
        roomId: 9
    }]
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncocsr4y/

Comment: This looks like a much better solution than mine! Taking into account the amount of code needed for each function, they would probably workout with similar footprints. Thanks for the suggestion, I don't know how I've gone this long without using objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitively use some kind of JSON nested dictionaries instead of arrays within arrays. It would take a little more space to transfer and to save in the database, but it will be more explicit for yourself and for other developers who will develop your project.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it all inside js before I save, and I have a pretty limited knowledge of JSON. I'll definitely look into this though, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can use the structure like in Matt Whetton's answer and then `json_string = JSON.stringify(property)` to convert it to JSON string and `property = JSON.parse(json_string)` to convert it back to JavaScript object.